# get Undefined Error in javascript code

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a foreach to get messages in database,My code is here:

```
<form action="/Send/Message/Reply" method="POST" id="sendReply">
    {{csrf_field()}}
  <textarea class="text-right" cols="80" rows="5" id="messageReply">
  </textarea>
  <input type="hidden" value="{{$message->id}}" id="messageId">
  <div class="footer text-right">
       <button type="submit" class="S-products">Send</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Now I Want to get message id and Reply_Content in javascript with axios by this code:

```
(function()
 {
document.querySelector('#sendReply').addEventListener('submit',function (e) {
   var messageReply = document.querySelector('#messageReply').value;
   var messageId = document.querySelector('#messageId').value;
   console.log(messageId)
   axios.post(this.action,{
        'messageReply' : messageReply,
        'messageId' : messageId,
         '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()
          })
   })
   })();
```

Bu i get messageId as Undefined,How I can Fix this problem?

Comment: Can you please just show the log of document.querySelector('#messageId')

Comment: Is this angular project?

Comment: What is the exact error? Access property of undefined? variable is undefined? Note your code is inside an IIFE, so if this code is above where your elements are, ie `<script>` is before your `<input>` then possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: @UllasHunka log of document.querySelector('#messageId') is undefined

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks this worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem with this code:

```
 var messageId = document.getElementById('messageId').value;
```

Comment: `querySelector('#messageId')` and `getElementById('messageId')` are effectively the same thing they both find the first element with an id value of `messageId`. You would of had to have changed some other code, changed its position in the html document, etc